# How to sync fish's universal variables across different computers?

Tags: fish

If you change some universal variables, how do you sync them across computers? The comments on the fishd.* files make it seem like a bad idea to sync those files. And fishd's man pages don't seem to indicate it's user serviceable.

Answer (score 1):

I put them in my config.fish file and sync that file between computers:

```
set -qUx EDITOR;  or set -Ux EDITOR vim
set -qUx VISUAL;  or set -Ux VISUAL vim
set -qUx LESS;    or set -Ux LESS "-iX"
set -qUx LC_TIME; or set -Ux LC_TIME POSIX
# ...
```