# How to migrate universal variables between computers in fish shell

Tags: fish

I recently changed laptops. I have all the original files for fish configuration, including the `~/.config/fish/fish_variables`. But I cannot source that file and it says I cannot change it. So, how do I get my universal variables back?

Comment: @ridiculous_fish can you reply here, the other question got closed.
And if you can explain why the file says it can't be edited and then it can, it would be a plus.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill for marking as a duplicate rather than "Need details".  I think RidiculousFish's answer from the SO question would still be a useful addition to [the duplicate](https://superuser.com/q/722617/1210833).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds That's for him to add

Comment: @DavidPostill Of course, that's exactly what I meant.  It's a reply to the OP asking RF to post the answer, which should be done on the linked question now that this one is closed.  Wasn't implying that *you* should copy the answer.  Probably would have been better if I'd separated it into two replies to avoid the confusion ...